# Alive Supervision Mechanism in WDGM

Tags: autosar

Iam working on WDGM demo, I have configured the demo  with proper WDG,WDGIF,WDGM requirements,its compiled sucessfully,but  not able to achieve Alive Supervision mechanism on the hardware,its entering reset in TRACE32 whenever i check  for the Alive result  increment

I have  written the below code in the application ,please correct me if iam wrong.pls  correct me with the  proper code

```
 if (WdgM_GetCheckedCPAliveCounterData (CPData, IntRamIdx, &AliveCounter) != E_OK)
    {
      AliveResult = WDGM_RESULT_INCORRECT;
    }
    else
    {

      if ((AliveCounter < (CPAliveCfg->ExpectedAliveIndication - CPAliveCfg->MinMargin)) ||
          (AliveCounter > (CPAliveCfg->ExpectedAliveIndication + CPAliveCfg->MaxMargin)))
      {
        AliveResult = WDGM_RESULT_INCORRECT;
      }
      else
      {
        AliveResult = WDGM_RESULT_CORRECT;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Which demo are you talking about? Also which venfor? And did you actually have some SWC to actually report Alive status to WdgM?

Comment: Here i need  to know an example  how alive supervision  works with alive indication max and  min margin,supervision  refernce  cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ping the WDGM with checkpoints when they are reached - are you doing that?

WdgM_CheckpointReached(SEID, CPID)

Initial and final checkpoints are mandatory.